# When using Qt Creator with CMake, why do I not have to manually link the MSVC libraries?

Tags: c++, sdk, linker, libraries

Whenever I want to use 3rd party library code in my Qt creator CMake project, I have to link the library to my executable in my CMakeLists.txt so that the code can be used.

However, if I want to use code from e.g, MSVC 2010, or the Windows 10 software development kit, all I have to do is download and install it, and if then the code is ready to use.

Why is this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior while searching dependencies in Windows is to look in all the system locations first, then the current directory, and finally any user-defined paths. That is why you don't have to explicitly link the Windows 10 SDK libraries.